# CSS/Javascript not binding on dynamic html append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to bind html dynamically from angular controller

```
SkillsApp.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {
$scope.getAllCategories = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/Categories/GetAllCategories",
        method: 'GET',
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.categoriesList = response;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categoriesList.length; i++)
        {
            var categoryyy = '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".commercial">' + $scope.categoriesList[i].Name + '</a></li>';                
            $('#Category').append(categoryyy);
        }           

    });
};
```

Result Html:

```
<ol class="type" id="Category">                                
   <li><a href="#" data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".residential">Residential</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</a></li>
  </ol>
```

Target Html:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 RESIDENTIAL">
  <div class="portfolio-item">
   <div class="hover-bg">
    <a href="img/portfolio/01-large.jpg" title="Project Title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1">
     <div class="hover-text">
       <h4>Project Name</h4>
     </div>
     <img src="~/img/portfolio/01-small.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Project Title">
   </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

But the above code was not binding to the target element.

The same code works perfectly if it is static html code.

Kindly help me where i am doing wrong.

**To be more specific :**
Due to dynamic binding of html the DOM was not able to bind **data-filter**
Is there anyway to refresh DOM objects after the dynamic html binding?

Comment: This is not the right angular way to achieve want you want. Have à look à `ng-repeat` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I guess here nothing to do with angular, i will get same result, Again it will fail on binding. Instead of data-filter, href will work.

Answer (score 1):

To loop into arrays I recommend to use `ng-repeat` directive have a look at [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

*AngularJS* is not *Jquery* see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) to a better understanding on how angularJS works

**Also:**
Are you setting your app with `ng-app="SkillsApp"`
Are you setting your controller with `ng-controller="homeController"`
Do you call `getAllCategories()` somewhere ? eg: `ng-init="getAllCategories()"`

**Example**

```
SkillsApp.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {
$scope.getAllCategories = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/Categories/GetAllCategories",
        method: 'GET',
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.categoriesList = response;
    });
};


<body ng-app="SkillsApp" ng-controller="homeController" ng-init="getAllCategories()" >
    <ol class="type"> 
        <li ng-repeat="categorie in categoriesList">
            <a href="#">{{categorie.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess here nothing to do with angular, i will get same result, Again it will fail on binding. Instead of data-filter, href will work.

Comment: what `data-filter` is supposed to do ? There is no `data-filter` build in directive in `angularjs`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a snippet this code

```
$scope.categoriesList = [];
```

Because you should collect data in to array inside $scope. Btw, if you want to code cleaner, you can use service or factory. Here it is the [LINK](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Try to see the diferent of service and factory in angular. Cheers